# Why do some smart phone chargers charges faster?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

I'm trying to design a cellphone charger for my Oppo F5 Youth phone with a Li-ion battery and 3500mAh capacity. My design objective is to charge my phone within an hour, with that goal. **What are the things I need to consider to enable fast charging capabilities?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the phone is meant to charge via a USB cable, then the charging speed is defined by the relevant USB standards, and possibly proprietary standards defined by the manufacturer.

Charging speed is also determined by charging circuit in the phone itself.  If the charging circuit in the phone only draws a little current, then the battery won't charge fast, no matter what charger its connected to.

One possible option is to use the [USB Battery Charging (BC) 1.2 Specifiaction](https://www.usb.org/document-library/battery-charging-v12-spec-and-adopters-agreement).  That specification allows for charging at 5V, and up to 1.5A.

- The "Oppo F5 Youth phone" uses a Li-Pol, 3.85V, 3200mAh battery.
- Typically, a USB port runs at 5V.

Assuming your charger is 90% efficient and outputs 5V, 1.5A, your charge time would be...
3200mAh * 3.85V / 5V / 0.9 / 1.5A = 1.825 hours

The next step up would be to implement portions of the [USB C specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf), which can deliver up to 3A.  See section 4.6 on page 217.  I would bet that most of the 15W USB-C chargers out there are implemented this way.  3A would be enough current to charge the battery in under an hour, provided that the circuit in the phone actually attempts to draw that much.

Finally, there is the USB-C / Power Delivery (PD), which can deliver up to 20V and 5A.

Answer (score 0):

Because some chargers adhere to the standard for fast charging a phone with the same standard.

Like to fast charge an older iPhone required resistors on the data line and to fast charge an older galaxy phone you needed Samsung Adaptive Fast Charge. Or newer phones require QC2 then QC3 or USB C PD with the right profiles or Apple certified MFi.

The max charge is determined by the standard and the phone. You need to design your charger with that in mind. The specifics of which are either public or privately documented (aka pay wall).

Answer (score 0):

Fast charge may cause the battery overheating. The battery temperature should be supervised.

Comment: Hi, Please ignore my earlier (now deleted) comment. Your post doesn't answer the *title* of the question, but it does answer part of the *text* of the question, so I have moved it back to be an answer. Sorry for the interruption.